# I have a MacBook Air and I lost (forgot) my Admin (root) password

Tags: macos, password, root, administrator

I have lost or forgotten the root password.  is there a way to recover it or reset it?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways. If you account is in the sudoers list, you can use this command:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Otherwise, boot into Recovery Mode

1. Restart the Mac.
2. Right after you hear the chime, press and hold the Command and the R keys for a few seconds, then release. Soon, you'll see the Apple logo and spinning gear.
   This will force the Mac to boot into OS X on the recovery partition that was created when you installed OS X 10.7 or later.
3. When booting is complete, you'll see a window of "OS X Utilities." You won't do anything there. Instead, you'll go to the Menu bar at the top and select Utilities > Terminal.
4. In the terminal window, type the following and press the Return key.

   `resetpassword`
5. A new window will open and click on the volume of interest and select the desired user account in the popup. Then enter the new password twice. A password hint is optional. Click "Save."
6. Go back to the Apple Menu at the top. Select OS X Utilities > Quit OS X Utilities. That will prompt you to restart the Mac.

You can find the guide here to reset the root password [here](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/os-x-mavericks-how-to-easily-reset-ther-administrator-password).